# Vala : Networking with GIO / Socket example doesn't work

Tags: outputstream, vala, gio

I'm trying to copy the "server example" from http://live.gnome.org/Vala/GIONetworkingSample.

But when I try to compile, I have the following error :

```
./src/server/Anais.vala:51.4-51.34: error: 2 missing arguments for `ssize_t GLib.OutputStream.write (void* buffer, size_t count, GLib.Cancellable? cancellable = null)'
            output.write( header.str.data );
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
./src/server/Anais.vala:52.4-52.31: error: 2 missing arguments for `ssize_t GLib.OutputStream.write (void* buffer, size_t count, GLib.Cancellable? cancellable = null)'
            output.write( content.data );
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Compilation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
make: *** [build-server] Erreur 1
```

I tryed to understand, what the error message means. So I looked at the documentation :
http://www.valadoc.org/references/gio-2.0/0.11.5/GLib.OutputStream.write.html

But as I'm not used to use glib and/or any library for client/server, I don't understand what I should do.

Could someone say to me how to use the `OutputStream` with Vala ?

**NB** : For information, I'm using valac 0.10.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That example is listed as requiring Vala >= 0.11.0 -- the API is changed with every odd-numbered minor release (so 0.11.x is the development series leading to the stable 0.12.x), and it seems that the API has changed since 0.10.x

If you're on Linux, which distribution are you on? Most should have Vala 0.12.x if you have a recent enough release installed.

Comment: I'm using trisquel Linux. I suppose I could compile vala by my own... I'll take a look. Thanks.

Comment: It's ok, I compiled valac by my own and installed alternate version of other packages, following : https://danious.wordpress.com/2011/06/04/installation-of-synapse-on-trisquel-gnulinux/ .